# Copying the first 100 resulted rows after applying a specific criteria to my table

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to take only the first 100 resulted rows after this:

`=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30`?

Here is my code, which I recorded it.

Thank you in advance.
I hope someone to help me.

```
Sub philoly_3()
'
' philoly_3 Macro
'

    Sheets("Graph data").Select
    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Criteria"
    Range("J2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30"
    Range("J2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J50000")
    Range("J2:J50000").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Input"
    Range("F2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$50000").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("A1:I1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All moments").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("F2").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Sheets("All moments").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("All moments").Move Before:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("Graph data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$50000").AutoFilter Field:=10
    Range("I50000").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("B2").Select

    philoly_11

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `the first 100 resulted rows`?

Comment: When I apply the "=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30" then I have a new row that has "yes" and "No" , every time that the "yes" appears this code collects these data and copy them somewhere else. But now I want only the first 100 each time that this "=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30" is "yes"

Comment: Now I included all my code. sorry that I left it out before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. Just modify to your needs and implement it in your code. For this, my data range was `=B2:E481`. My criteria YES/NO is in column E. I copied the first 100 ranges (B:D) that were yes in column E, and pasted them into Z2.

```
Sub COPY_100_FIRST_YES()
Dim i As Byte
Dim MyRanges As String
Dim MyYesRanges() As String
Dim MyFinalSelection As Range

Range("E2").Select 'first row of my YES/NO column
i = 0
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = "" Or i = 100 'Loop until you have 100 yes or there is no more data
    If ActiveCell.Value = "yes" Then
        i = i + 1
        If MyRanges = "" Then
            MyRanges = ActiveCell.Row
        Else
            MyRanges = MyRanges & "||" & ActiveCell.Row
        End If
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

 'Now I have all rows that are YES and I know the columns i want to copy, in my case is columns B to D, so

 MyYesRanges() = Split(MyRanges, "||")

 For i = 0 To UBound(MyYesRanges) Step 1
    If i = 0 Then
        Set MyFinalSelection = Range("B" & MyYesRanges(i) & ":D" & MyYesRanges(i))
    Else
        Set MyFinalSelection = Application.Union(MyFinalSelection, Range("B" & MyYesRanges(i) & ":D" & MyYesRanges(i)))
    End If
 Next i


MyFinalSelection.Copy

'Paste where you want them
Range("Z2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding and thank you for your answer. The column "I" that is "Amount" has values from 1-1600 and only increases. At some times remains stable for further than 30 seconds. I would like to collect these data when the amount is stable but I only need the first 100 raws of every time that the amount is stable. I don`t want only the first 100 rows when the criteria is yes. because in this way it gives me only the 100 rows of the first time when the amount("I") is stable. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Well, I answered what you said `But now I want only the first 100 each time that this "=COUNTIFS(R2C9:R50000C9,RC[-1])>30" is "yes"`. If you need more criteria, modify your question to ask EXACTLY what you want to get, You are welcome and I hope you find your answer